# How Javascript stores objects as keys

Tags: javascript

We know that

```js
let obj1 = {};
obj1.x = "value";

let obj2 = {"key":"value"};
obj2[obj1] = "another value";
console.log(obj2[obj1]);
```

Above will print the "another value" properly on the console. Need to understand how. Does it store the address of obj1 for the key to match with the value?

Comment: _"Need to understand how."_ - then do a `console.log(obj2);`, and see if that helps with the understanding.

Comment: assignment this way will simply call String(obj1) when creating the key "[object Object]"

Comment: Object keys are either strings or `Symbol` and anything which is not a Symbol (like your case) will be converted to a string, hence you can check that by doing: `console.log(obj2[obj1.toString()]);` which will give you the exact result as `console.log(obj2[obj1]);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Object property names can be strings or Symbols. Anything that is not a Symbol will be converted to a string.

A plain object's `toString` method will convert it to `"[object Object]"`.

You can see that string if you log the entire object.

```js
let obj1 = {};
obj1.x = "value";

let obj2 = {"key":"value"};
obj2[obj1] = "another value";
console.log(obj2);

console.log(obj1.toString());
```

This does, of course, mean that if you try to set `ob2[obj3]` at some point, with another object, then even if `obj3` is a different object it will still be converted to the same string and overwrite the previous value.